# Вывод данных из БД в DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

не смог найти тему с ответом на мой вопрос.
Есть база данных на локальном сервере MySql. 
Создаю приложение Windows Forms, соединение устанавливается с БД, но данные не выводятся в DataGridView. Точнее выводятся, но пишет System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] за место данных и то только в 1-ом столбце. Не могу понять что это. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать работоспособную программу

Вот код соединения с БД. Метод public List[] Select() создаёт список для вывода.

```
class DBconnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server, database, uid, password;

        public DBconnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "catalog_personal";
            uid = "root";
            password = " ";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = " SERVER =" + server + " ;" + " DATABASE =" +
            database + " ;" + " UID =" + uid + " ;" + "PASSWORD =" + password + " ;";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
        //Открываем соединение
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                // При обработке ошибок вы можете основывать ответ вашего приложения
                // по номеру ошибки.
                // Два наиболее распространенных номера ошибок при подключении:
                // 0: не удается подключиться к серверу.
                // 1045: неверное имя пользователя и / или пароль.

                switch(ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Невозможно подключиться к серверу, " +
                            "связаться с админ-панелью");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Неверное имя пользователя / пароль, " +
                            "пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        //Закрываем соединение
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        public List<string>[] Select()
        {
            string query = " SELECT * FROM personal";

            //Создаем список для сохранения результа вывода

            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[4];

            list[0] = new List<string>();
            list[1] = new List<string>();
            list[2] = new List<string>();
            list[3] = new List<string>();

            //Открываем соединение
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Создаем команду
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                //Создаем читатель данных и выполняем команду чтения
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    list[0].Add(dataReader[0].ToString());
                    list[1].Add(dataReader[1].ToString());
                    list[2].Add(dataReader[2].ToString());
                    list[3].Add(dataReader[3].ToString());
                }
                this.CloseConnection();

                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                return list;
            }
        }
    }
```

Код в Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadData();
        }
        private void LoadData()
        {
            DBconnect db = new DBconnect();

            foreach (var s in db.Select())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
            }
        }

    }
```

Вот что получается в результате, прикрепляю скрин
[image: Результат ошибки]

Comment: почему не использовать MySqlDataAdapter? Он сразу положит результат в DataTable. а его в свою очередь передадите в dataGridView1.DataSource. Select и LoadData будут из 2х строчек и соответственно без ошибок.

Comment: Не разу не имел дело с DataAdapter, в программировании новичок. Если черканёте строчек кода, буду неимоверно признателен :)

Comment: С адаптером может и удобно, но тогда ваш код получится жестко связанным с БД. Гибче подход работать все таки в парадигме ООП и создавать классы модели, т.е. вы должны создать класс Сотрудник и из БД извлекать и отображать список Сотрудников, а не массив стрингов или виртуальное зеркало таблицы БД коей является работа через адаптер.

Comment: А работу через адаптер можно посмотреть в youtube, достаточно зайти на сайт и задать поиск `c# mysql insert update delete` и получите кучу индуского инглиша и разной степени паршивости примеров такой работы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую разобраться. Если не разберусь, придётся заново открыть вопрос)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим подробнее ваш пример.
Вот вы "набросали" на форму контролы, и вам нужно начать программировать работу с ними. Что бы тут хотелось бы...

Во-первых, не торопитесь сразу создавать БД и подключаться к ней. Для быстрого прототипирования приложения БД не нужна и даже вредна, т.к. отвлекает время и внимание на работу с ней.

Во-вторых, в прил. необходимо выделить слои, минимально 3: слой отображения (визуальный интерфейс), слой модели предметной области с кот. работает ваше прил. и слой хранения (это как раз работа с БД).

Начнем с создания модели. У нас модель достаточно простая. Я добавил еще статич. метод для клонирования экземпляра класса, зачем? Объясню ниже.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //порядковый номер для отображения в DGV
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    //имя
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //фамилия
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public Employee(int id, string firstName = "<?>", string lastName = "<?>", string phone = "<?>")
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Phone = phone;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение клонированного экземпляра
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="employee">существующий экземпляр</param>
    /// <returns>клон существующего сотрудника</returns>
    public static Employee GetClone(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee is null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));

        return new Employee(employee.Id)
        {
            FirstName = employee.FirstName,
            LastName = employee.LastName,
            Phone = employee.Phone,
        };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}: {FirstName} {LastName}";
    }
}
```

Слой хранения начнем с абстракции, с создания интерфейса репозитория.

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    //получение всех
    Task<Result<List<Employee>>> GetEmployees();
    //добавление
    Task<Result<int>> AddEmployee(Employee employee);
    //удаление
    Task<Result<int>> RemoveEmployee(int id);
    //обновление
    Task<Result<int>> UpdateEmployee(Employee emp);
}
```

Здесь мы объявляем все нужные нам для работы методы. Кстати, вы можете начинать прямо с пустого интерфейса, и по мере надобности добавлять в него нужные члены. Обратите внимание, что предполагается работа в асинхронном режиме, и да, есть еще какой-то `Result<T>`!

`Result<T>` - это пример т.н. монады, спец. класса для возвращения результата в случае если в методе возникнет ошибка или результат может быть равным `null`. Подробнее [см.видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGDo0gtWJ-Q). Вот его код

```
/// <summary>
/// Монада Result для возвращения результата вместо null
/// и для случаев когда возникает Exception, а результат из метода
/// нужно возвращать какой-то
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class Result<T>
{
    public readonly T Value;
    public readonly string Error;

    //ctors
    public Result(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Error = String.Empty;
    }
    public Result(string error)
    {
        Error = error;
    }

    public bool HasValue => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Error);

    public static implicit operator bool(Result<T> result)
    {
        return result.HasValue;
    }
}
```

Теперь вернемся к интерфейсу приложения. Код формы такой

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    //Источник данных для DGV
    private BindingSource _bsEmployees;
    //редактируемый сотрудник
    private BindingSource _bsCurrentEmployee;
    //работа с БД
    private IEmployeeRepository _repo;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Text = "Пример работы с MySql";

        //установка привязок
        SetBindings();

        this.Load += MainForm_Load;
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //тестовый репозиторий
        _repo = new TestRepository();

        //Загрузка данных
        LoadData();

        //кнопки
        _buttonAdd.Click += ButtonAdd_Click;
        _buttonRemove.Click += ButtonRemove_Click;
        _buttonSave.Click += ButtonSave_Click;
        _buttonNext.Click += ButtonNext_Click;
        _buttonPrev.Click += ButtonPrev_Click;
        //клик по строке в DGV
        _dataGridViewEmployees.MouseClick += (s, a) => SetCurrentEmployee();
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        _bsEmployees = new BindingSource();
        _bsEmployees.DataSource = typeof(List<Employee>);
        //привязки для DGV
        _dataGridViewEmployees.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridViewEmployees.DataSource = _bsEmployees;
        //привязки у столбцов
        _columnNumber.DataPropertyName = nameof(Employee.OrderNumber);
        _columnFirstName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Employee.FirstName);
        _columnLastName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Employee.LastName);
        _columnPhone.DataPropertyName = nameof(Employee.Phone);

        //текстбоксы
        _bsCurrentEmployee = new BindingSource();
        _bsCurrentEmployee.DataSource = new List<Employee> { new Employee(0) };
        _textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsCurrentEmployee, nameof(Employee.FirstName));
        _textBoxLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsCurrentEmployee, nameof(Employee.LastName));
        _textBoxPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsCurrentEmployee, nameof(Employee.Phone));
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        //получаем
        var result = await _repo.GetEmployees();
        if (result)
        {
            //извлекаем
            List<Employee> employees = result.Value;
            //пронумеровываем
            int i = 1;
            employees.ForEach(e => e.OrderNumber = i++);
            //отображаем
            _bsEmployees.DataSource = employees;
            _bsEmployees.MoveFirst();
            SetCurrentEmployee();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.Error, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //курсор на последнего
        _bsEmployees.MoveLast();
        //след.порядковый номер
        int number = (_bsEmployees.Current as Employee).OrderNumber + 1;
        //добавляем нового
        _bsEmployees.Add(new Employee(0) { OrderNumber = number });
        //выделяем его
        _bsEmployees.MoveNext();
        SetCurrentEmployee();
        //выделяем имя для редактирования
        _textBoxFirstName.Focus();
    }

    private async void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SwitchOnWaiting();

        var current = (Employee)_bsCurrentEmployee.Current;
        Result<int> result;

        try
        {
            if (current.Id == 0)
            {
                //добавляем нового сотрудника
                result = await _repo.AddEmployee(current);
            }
            else
            {
                //иначе обновляем существующего сотрудника
                result = await _repo.UpdateEmployee(current);
            }

            if (result)
            {
                //перечитываем данные
                LoadData();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            SwitchOffWaiting();
        }

        if(!result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.Error, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private async void ButtonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SwitchOnWaiting();

        //получаем текущего
        var employee = (Employee)_bsEmployees.Current;
        Result<int> result;
        try
        {
            //удаляем из БД
            result = await _repo.RemoveEmployee(employee.Id);
            if (result)
            {
                //удаляем из отображения
                _bsEmployees.Remove(employee);
                _bsEmployees.MoveFirst();
                SetCurrentEmployee();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            SwitchOffWaiting();
        }

        if (!result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result.Error, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    private void ButtonPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bsEmployees.MovePrevious();
        SetCurrentEmployee();
    }

    private void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bsEmployees.MoveNext();
        SetCurrentEmployee();
    }

    private void SetCurrentEmployee()
    {
        if (_bsEmployees.Count > 0)
        {
            _bsCurrentEmployee.List[0] = Employee.GetClone((Employee)_bsEmployees.Current);

        }
        else
        {
            _bsCurrentEmployee.List[0] = new Employee(0);
        }

        _bsCurrentEmployee.ResetItem(0);
    }

    private void SwitchOnWaiting()
    {
        foreach (var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
        _dataGridViewEmployees.Enabled = false;
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }

    private void SwitchOffWaiting()
    {
        foreach (var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Enabled = true;
        }
        _dataGridViewEmployees.Enabled = true;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

На что хотелось бы обратить внимание.

Работаем через привязки, используем для этого два экземпляра `BindingSource`, один для `DataGridView`, второй для текстбоксов текущего редактируемого или создаваемого нового сотрудника. По клику на `DGV` или переходе с пом.кнопок к следующему или предыдущему создается клон и привязывается текстбоксам. Сделано так для того, чтобы исключить одновременное изменение свойств выделенного сотрудника в `DGV` и пользователь понимал, что необходимо нажать кнопку `Сохранить` для запоминания изменений.

В методе `MainForm_Load()` сделано подключение к фейковой БД `_repo = new TestRepository();` или точнее классу реализующему `IEmployeeRepository` c тестовыми данными. Рассмотрим его

```
class TestRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private List<Employee> _employees;
    public TestRepository()
    {
        _employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee(1, "Иван", "Голунов", "+7561234567"),
            new Employee(2, "Сергей", "Смирнов", "+77861234567"),
            new Employee(3, "Дарья", "Смирнова", "+798475563"),
            new Employee(4, "Кристина", "Семяжко", "+7304985023"),
            new Employee(5, "Владимир", "Драгунов", "+73431234567"),
        };
    }

    public Task<Result<List<Employee>>> GetEmployees()
    {
        var result = new List<Employee>();
        foreach (var e in _employees)
        {
            var emp = new Employee(e.Id, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Phone);
            result.Add(emp);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new Result<List<Employee>>(result));
    }

    public Task<Result<int>> AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.FirstName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.FirstName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Result<int>("Введите имя сотрудника."));
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.LastName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LastName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Result<int>("Введите фамилию сотрудника."));
        }

        if (employee is null || employee.Id > 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));

        if (_employees.Count > 0)
        {
            employee.Id = _employees.Max(e => e.Id) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            employee.Id = 1;
        }
        _employees.Add(employee);

        return Task.FromResult(new Result<int>(1));
    }

    public Task<Result<int>> RemoveEmployee(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id));

        var emp = _employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        if (emp != null)
        {
            _employees.Remove(emp);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new Result<int>(1));
    }

    public Task<Result<int>> UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.FirstName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.FirstName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Result<int>("Введите имя сотрудника."));
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.LastName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LastName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Result<int>("Введите фамилию сотрудника."));
        }

        var emp = _employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == employee.Id);
        if (emp != null)
        {
            emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            emp.LastName = employee.LastName;
            emp.Phone = employee.Phone;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new Result<int>(1));
    }
}
```

Представьте на минутку, вы фрилансер и у вас заказ на подобную программу. Вам нужно быстро разработать прототип и предоставить заказчику, чтоб он мог этот прототип запустить и посмотреть, оценить и проч. Если бы вы использовали сразу подключение к реальной БД у вас бы возникли трудности, не правда ли... А так без проблем, компилируем и отправляем экзешник по почте.
[image: пример работы приложения]

Заказчик доволен? :) Пишем работу с реальной БД.

```
class MySqlRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    public MySqlRepository()
    { }

    private MySqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConn"].ToString();
        var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs);
        //чтоб избежать проблем с русским языком
        builder.CharacterSet = "utf8";
        return new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }

    public async Task<Result<List<Employee>>> GetEmployees()
    {
        var list = new List<Employee>();

        try
        {
            using (var con = GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM employees";
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var emp = new Employee(reader.GetInt32(0));
                        emp.FirstName = reader.GetString(1);
                        emp.LastName = reader.GetString(2);
                        emp.Phone = reader.GetString(3);

                        list.Add(emp);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            return new Result<List<Employee>>(GetUserFriendlyErrorMessage(ex));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Result<List<Employee>>(ex.Message);
        }

        return new Result<List<Employee>>(list);
    }

    public async Task<Result<int>> AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.FirstName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.FirstName))
        {
            return new Result<int>("Введите имя сотрудника.");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.LastName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LastName))
        {
            return new Result<int>("Введите фамилию сотрудника.");
        }

        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var con = GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name, phone)" +
                    " VALUES(@firstName, @lastName, @phone)";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@firstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200)
                { Value = employee.FirstName });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@lastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
                { Value = employee.LastName });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@phone", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45)
                {
                    Value = employee.Phone ?? (object)System.DBNull.Value
                });

                con.Open();
                result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            return new Result<int>(GetUserFriendlyErrorMessage(ex));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Result<int>(ex.Message);
        }

        return new Result<int>(result);
    }

    public async Task<Result<int>> RemoveEmployee(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id));

        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var con = GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE id =@id";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32)
                { Value = id });

                con.Open();
                result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            return new Result<int>(GetUserFriendlyErrorMessage(ex));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Result<int>(ex.Message);
        }

        return new Result<int>(result);
    }

    public async Task<Result<int>> UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.FirstName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.FirstName))
        {
            return new Result<int>("Введите имя сотрудника.");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.LastName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LastName))
        {
            return new Result<int>("Введите фамилию сотрудника.");
        }

        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var con = GetConnection())
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE employees" +
                    " SET first_name = @firstName, last_name = @lastName, phone = @phone" +
                    " WHERE id =@id";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@firstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200)
                { Value = employee.FirstName });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@lastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
                { Value = employee.LastName });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@phone", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45)
                {
                    Value = employee.Phone ?? (object)System.DBNull.Value
                });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32)
                { Value = employee.Id });

                con.Open();
                result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            return new Result<int>(GetUserFriendlyErrorMessage(ex));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Result<int>(ex.Message);
        }

        return new Result<int>(result);
    }

    private string GetUserFriendlyErrorMessage(MySqlException ex)
    {
        var message = String.Empty;
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                if (ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("Unknown"))
                {
                    message = "Неверное название схемы или таблицы.";
                }
                else if (ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("Access"))
                {
                    message = "Неверное имя или пароль доступа.";
                }
                else
                {
                    message = ex.Message;
                }
                break;
            case 1042:
                message = "Сервер по указанному адресу не доступен." +
                    "\nОшибка ожидания.";
                break;
            case 1045:
                message = "Неверное имя пользователя или пароль, " +
                    "\nпожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.";
                break;
            default:
                message = ex.Message;
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

В методе `GetConnection()` параметры соединения читаются из файла `App.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
       <startup> 
           <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
       </startup>
       <connectionStrings>
           <add name="MySqlConn"
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
     connectionString="Server=192.168.0.250;Port=3306;Database=EmployeesDb;Uid=admin;
      Pwd=Mysql17;"/>
      </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

Для работы с этим классом, нужно вернуться в код формы и в методе `MainForm_Load()` изменить строчку получения экземпляра репозитория `_repo = new MySqlRepository();`.

Да, и не забудьте сначала получить деньги от заказчика :)

Пример лежит [здесь.](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/WinFormsMySql)

Comment: Спасибо большое :) Это даже больше чем я просил или ожидал :)
Но достаточно много надо разобрать в коде теперь, но зато буду знать как и что :) ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Да, пожалуйста. Давно уже хотел подобный подробный ответ дать, т.к. очень часто появляются вопросы по написанию приложений с работой с БД. Кстати, я сделал небольшой рефакторинг, перенес проверку введенных данных из репозитория в форму, т.к. это более правильно с точки зрения архитектуры. Изменения смотрите на гитхабе по старой ссылке.

Answer (score 3):

Для конструирования строки соединения можно использовать специальный класс-билдер.

При установлении соединения вы оставили только два случая в switch/case, а остальные отбрасываются. В итоге пользователь не получит никакого сообщения, если что-то пойдёт не так. Нужно, например, добавить дополнительную ветку default.

Современная разработка подразумевает использования моделей данных. Свойства класса-модели должны соответствовать колонкам в таблице базы данных. Я не знаю, какие у вас колонки, но, судя по форме, это Имя, Фамилия, Телефон. Поэтому, класс-модель будет такой:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Добавьте необходимые свойства с нужными типами (например, Id типа int и т. п.)

При чтении данных из БД создаём экземпляры нашего класса-модели, заполняем его свойства и добавляем в список.

```
class DBconnect
{
    private readonly MySqlConnection connection;

    public DBconnect()
    {
        var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        builder.Server = "localhost";
        builder.Database = "catalog_personal";
        builder.UserID = "root";
        //builder.Password = "";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }

    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Невозможно подключиться к серверу, " +
                        "связаться с админ-панелью");
                    break;
                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Неверное имя пользователя / пароль, " +
                        "пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз");
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private void CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public List<Person> Select()
    {
        string query = " SELECT * FROM personal";
        var list = new List<Person>();

        if (OpenConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    var person = new Person();
                    person.FirstName = dataReader.GetString(0);
                    person.LastName = dataReader.GetString(1);
                    person.Phone = dataReader.GetString(2);
                    list.Add(person);
                }
            }
            CloseConnection();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Также используем привязку данных (binding) вместо ручного добавления.

```
private void LoadData()
{
    var db = new DBconnect();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Select();
}
```

Comment: по настоящему правильный ответ про модели

Answer (score 1):

Переписал ваш код через MySqlDataAdapter, он очень сильно сократился.

Как упражнение, можете переписать его через модели (будет чуть побольше и посложнее, но правильнее и гибчее).

```
class DBconnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server, database, uid, password;

        public DBconnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            ...
        }
        //Открываем соединение
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            ...
        }
        //Закрываем соединение
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            ...
        }
        public DataTable Select()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand.Connection = this.connection;
                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM personal";
                da.Fill(dt);
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Код в Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadData();
        }
        private void LoadData()
        {
            DBconnect db = new DBconnect();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Select();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `public List<string>[] Select()` и при этом `return dt;` ? Не тот же тип!

Comment: исправил. можете пока писать решение с моделями ;-)

Comment: А вот я только сейчас финишировал :)

Comment: Большое спасибо всем :)