# Ошибка соединения с MySQL (The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception)

Tags: c#, mysql

В консольном приложении пытаюсь соединиться с СУБД MySQL

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();

```
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Соединение с СУБД MySQL установлено!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка установки соединения с СУБД MySQL: \n" + e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Класс "DBUtils"

```
class DBUtils
{
    public static MySqlConnection GetDBConnection()
    {
        string host = "localhost";
        int port = 3306;
        string database = "tc-db-main";
        string username = "username";
        string password = "password";

        return DBMySQLUtils.GetDBConnection(host, port, database, username, password);
    }
}
```

Класс "DBMySQLUtils"

```
class DBMySQLUtils
{
    public static MySqlConnection
            GetDBConnection(string host, int port, string database, string username, string password)
    {
        // Connection String.
        String connString = "Server=" + host + ";port=" + port + ";Database=" + database + ";uid=" + username + ";pwd=" + password;

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        return conn;
    }

}
```

При попытке соединения выскакивает ошибка. Уже перебрал множество вариантов решения, но все тщетно. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным или знает возможные варианты решения - буду признателен за совет.

Ошибка: **'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.**

[image: Выводимая ошибка при попытке соединения с СУБД]

Comment: Недавно писал ответ про работу с MySql, посмотрите последний класс репозитория в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542). или соседний ответ, там про билдер написано.