# Как при повторном выводе данных в datagridview обновить таблицу полностью

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Проблема в том, что при повторном нажатии на кнопку просмотра таблицы, в datagridview она продолжается, с первого id в таблице с оставляя старые данные. Как заставить программу при повторном нажатии на кнопку просмотра обновить таблицу? Не очень удобно выглядит, когда те же самые данные выводятся в ту же таблицу после данных от первого нажатия. Грубо говоря *нажатие* вывод id 1,2,3. *нажатие* вывод id 1,2,3,4. Без удаления данных от первого нажатия

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.connString;
        string sqlExpression = "SELECT * FROM readers";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new string[6]);
                    data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                    data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
                    data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
                    data[data.Count - 1][3] = reader[3].ToString();
                    data[data.Count - 1][4] = reader[4].ToString();
                    data[data.Count - 1][5] = reader[5].ToString();
                    data[data.Count - 1][6] = reader[6].ToString();
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            foreach (string[] s in data)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Как вы заполняете DataGridview ? код покажите

Comment: добавил код в текст вопроса

Comment: Пример на программу подобного рода https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 (не рекомендую)

---

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); //удаляет все записи из dataGridview
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "a";
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "b";
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = "c";
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "a1";
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = "b1";
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value = "c1";
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "a2";
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = "b2";
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value = "c2";
        }
```

### Вариант 2 (рекомендую)

создаем класс

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SurnName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }




private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(); // список содержит экземпляры класса Person


            Person p1 = new Person // инициализруем персону 1
            {
                Name = "name1",
                SurnName = "Surname1",
                Age = 1
            };

            persons.Add(p1); // добавляем в список

            Person p2 = new Person //инициализруем персону 2
            {
                Name = "name12",
                SurnName = "Surname12",
                Age = 2
            };

            persons.Add(p2); // добавляем в список

            dataGridView2.DataSource = persons; //присваиваем список DataGrirview (каждый раз присваивая новый список данные будут только из этого списка)

        }
```

### Ваш Код

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.connString;
    string sqlExpression = "SELECT * FROM readers";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(new string[6]);
                data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][3] = reader[3].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][4] = reader[4].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][5] = reader[5].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][6] = reader[6].ToString();
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close(); // соединение тоже надо закрывать 
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); //Вот эту строку добавить
        foreach (string[] s in data)
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: а вобше правельно использовать вариант 2  т.к с классом работать удобней , но это ваше дело