# Как вывести данные из базы данных на dataGridView1,если код считывающий находится в другом классе?

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать чтобы при загрузке формы данные из таблицы вывелись в dataGridVieW, но мной созданном методе View, в цикле while dataGridView зачеркивается красным и ошибка "dataGridView не существует в текущем контексте". Как сделать так чтобы я смог вывести данные вводя только команду dBase.View(); в Form_Load?
Код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DBase dBase = new DBase();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dBase.Connect();
            dBase.View(); //-> ЭТО
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            dBase.Close();
        }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != null && textBox2.Text != null && textBox3.Text != null)
            {
                dBase.Add(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text), textBox3.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    public class DBase
    {
        public DBase()
        {

        }
        public DBase(string name, int data, string function)
        {

        }
        SQLiteConnection connection;
        public void Connect()
        {
            connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=information.db;Version=3;");
            connection.Open();
        }
        public void Close()
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        public void View()
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read()) //-> ЭТО
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")), reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Data")), reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Function"))); //-> ЭТО
                }
        }
        public void Add(string name, int data, string function)
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Humans(Name, Data, Function) VALUES ( @Name, @Data, @Function)";
            command.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = name.ToUpper();
            command.Parameters.Add("@Data", System.Data.DbType.Int32).Value = data;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Function", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = function;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Подробный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542) как правильно отделять логику работы с БД от визуального интерфейса программы.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Не могу скачать пример, пишет File uploads require push access to this repository. Хотел изучить. Помогите пожалуйста. Ссылка: https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/WinFormsMySql

Comment: https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples и нажмите зеленую кнопку `Clone or download`

Comment: Проблема в том,что у меня нет такой кнопки

Comment: Она должна быть если пойдете по ссылке которую я дал.

Comment: Да нашел! Спасибо!