# Binding dataGridView с таблицей из БД(SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Подскажите как корректно сделать следующее действие:
есть таблица в БД(SQL Server) и есть WinForms приложение(записи таблицы БД находятся в dataGridView) по работе с данными этой самой таблицы.

Функционал по работе с записями таблицы из БД - CRUD.

Ну и есть задача: при внесении изменений в данные таблицы& отображать эти изменения в приложении.

& - CRUD осуществляется в обработчиках событий после нажатия на соответствующую кнопку.

Что у меня есть:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Users"].ConnectionString;

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                string select = "SELECT Login, Address, Number FROM UserData";
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, cnn);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
```

Пример добавления в таблицу:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand insert = cnn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserData(Login, Password, Address, Number, IsAdmin) " + "values(@login, @pass, @address, @number, @isAdmin)";
                        if(IsUniqLogin(cnn, textBox1.Text))
                        {
                            int isAdmin = -1;
                            if (radioButton1.Checked) isAdmin = 1;
                            else isAdmin = 0;

                            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", textBox1.Text);
                            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", CreatePasswordHash(textBox2.Text));
                            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox3.Text);
                            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", textBox4.Text);
                            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAdmin", isAdmin);
                            await insert.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                            MessageBox.Show("Добавление пользователя завершено успешно!", "Уведомление", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            groupBox1.Visible = false;
                            ClearTextBoxesGB1();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Указанный логин уже существует - введите другой", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                            textBox1.Clear();
                        }
```

Нужно, чтобы после добавления(в этом случае) в таблицу, записи в DGV имели актуальную информацию - то есть, чтобы была привязка между DGV и таблицей из БД.Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `DataGridView` - основная причина, почему я свалил в WPF с MVVM, там это делать вообще не надо: меняются данные - сам обновляется интерфейс, разработчики Microsoft сделали там всю грязную работу за нас. Ваша задача выполнима, но чтобы сделать это оптимально, надо вручную выполнять синхронизацию CollectionView и данных, отлавливая изменения и обновляя интерфейс. К сожалению, я не помню как обновлять таблицу, 3 года прошло стех пор, помню, там надо какой-то `Refresh()` вызывать.

Comment: @aepot пробовал Refresh(), Update(), Invalidate()...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542

Comment: Создайте метод, например `ReloadData`, вынесите туда код из конструктора. Кстати, никогда не добавляйте свой код в коструктор формы, можете поломать приложение, а потом долго разбираться. Для действий при запуске программы используйте событие `Form.Load`. Так вот, вызывайте новый метод тогда, когда вам надо переобновить таблицу. Метод тяжелый и грубый, но для начала сойдет.

Comment: @aepot думал об этом. Но вот загвостка:  у меня отражение данных в таблицу идёт асинхронно. И методы CRUD тоже асинхронные, поэтому, при вызове асинхронного метода отображения данных в DGV, в,также асинхронном методе,допустим,добавления, получается не очень хорошо.

Comment: @Bulson я так изначально делал. Не помогло в моем случае.

Comment: Или это 20-ти минутное [видео](https://youtu.be/p2SedMeLQo4)

Comment: Тогда это либо слишко сложно для меня, либо недостаточно кода, чтобы понять, что требуется. Может кто-то другой еще что скажет. А советом про унести код из конструктора в обработчик `Form.Load` настоятельно рекомендую воспользоваться.

Comment: @aepot спасиб, возьму на вооружение.