# CRUD - DataBase in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, ado.net, wpf-datagrid

Есть база данных MSSQL SERVER (library) в ней есть таблица Teachers нужно с помощью WPF взаимодействовать с таблицей (CRUD - операции)
Сделал интерфейс окна -
MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20 8 20 8" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
    
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="14">
            <MenuItem Header="Create" Click="Create_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Read" Click="Read_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Update"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
        </Menu>
 
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="GridContent">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="120"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FN}" Header="FirstName" Width="125"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LN}" Header="LastName" Width="80"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Подключился к бд, сделал запрос на чтение данных, **как теперь отобразить данные в grid?**
xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string connectString;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ConnectionString;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Read_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           try
           {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand()
                    {
                        CommandText = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Teachers",
                        Connection = sqlConnection,
                    };

                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand); 

                    
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    { 
                        while (reader.Read()) //<----------------вот здесь!!!!
                        {
                            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                            GridContent.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView(); 
                          
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                   
                }
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
        }
    }
```

app.congif:

```
<connectionStrings>
            <add name="Connect" 
                 connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=library; Integrated Security=True"/>
        </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Нынче так не пишут, тем более для WPF. Вам нужно создать модель предметной области, в вашем случае класс `Teacher` с нужными свойствами. Для быстрого создания прототипа приложения БД не нужна совсем, используйте тестовые данные из памяти. Отделите работу с БД в отдельный класс репозитория, используйте привязки вместо событий. Посмотрите ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542 который я писал для WinForms.

Comment: @Bulson Понял, а есть пример на каком-то ресурсе как это делать на WPF, а то не нашел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал специально для вас тот же пример, что и ранее написанный для [WinForms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542)
[image: пример работы]
Данный пример гитхабе [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WpfCRUD).

В качестве модели используется тот же класс `Employee`.
Интерфейс для работы с БД такой

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    //получение всех
    Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees();
    //добавление
    Task<int> AddEmployee(Employee employee);
    //удаление
    Task<int> RemoveEmployee(int id);
    //обновление
    Task<int> UpdateEmployee(Employee emp);
}
```

Репозиторий с тестовыми данными такой

```
class TestRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private List<Employee> _employees;
    public TestRepository()
    {
        _employees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee(1, "Иван", "Голунов", "+7561234567"),
            new Employee(2, "Сергей", "Смирнов", "+77861234567"),
            new Employee(3, "Дарья", "Смирнова", "+798475563"),
            new Employee(4, "Кристина", "Семяжко", "+7304985023"),
            new Employee(5, "Владимир", "Драгунов", "+73431234567"),
        };
    }

    public Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployees()
    {
        var result = new List<Employee>();
        foreach (var e in _employees)
        {
            var emp = new Employee(e.Id, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Phone);
            result.Add(emp);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public Task<int> AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.FirstName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.FirstName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.LastName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LastName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        if (employee is null || employee.Id > 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));

        if (_employees.Count > 0)
        {
            employee.Id = _employees.Max(e => e.Id) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            employee.Id = 1;
        }
        _employees.Add(employee);

        return Task.FromResult(employee.Id);
    }

    public Task<int> RemoveEmployee(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id));

        var emp = _employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        if (emp != null)
        {
            _employees.Remove(emp);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(id);
    }

    public Task<int> UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.FirstName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.FirstName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employee.LastName)
            || String.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.LastName))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        var emp = _employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == employee.Id);
        if (emp != null)
        {
            emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            emp.LastName = employee.LastName;
            emp.Phone = employee.Phone;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(employee.Id);
    }
}
```

Для примера еще есть реализация для SqlServer в классе [SqlRepository](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/blob/master/WpfCRUD/WpfUI/Data/SqlRepository.cs).

Проект написан с использованием `MVVM`.
`View` основана на `UserControl` и отображается в окне программы, сорян мне было лень, потому набросал контролы просто на канву, в реальном приложении так делать конечно не надо.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfUI.Views.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfUI.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="750">
<Canvas Height="400" Width="750">
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="99" Text="Имя"/>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="135" Text="Фамилия"/>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="171" Text="Телефон"/>
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="99" Text="{Binding FirstName}"  Width="120"/>
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="133" Text="{Binding LastName}" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="169" Text="{Binding Phone}" Width="120"/>
    <Button Content="Добавить" Command="{Binding Add}" Canvas.Left="62" Canvas.Top="225"/>
    <Button Content="Сохранить" Command="{Binding Save}" Canvas.Left="128" Canvas.Top="225" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Удалить" Command="{Binding Delete}" Canvas.Left="214" Canvas.Top="225"/>
    <Button Content="Назад" Command="{Binding Prev}" Canvas.Left="82" Canvas.Top="268"/>
    <Button Content="Вперед" Command="{Binding Next}" Canvas.Left="214" Canvas.Top="268"/>
    <DataGrid Height="358"
              Width="450"
              Canvas.Left="282"
              Canvas.Top="21"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              AlternatingRowBackground="LightCyan"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="П/Н" Binding="{Binding OrderNumber}" Width="50"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Телефон" Binding="{Binding Phone}" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Canvas>
```

На что следует обратить внимание? На привязки:

- для DataGrid источник данных это свойство `People` у `ViewModel`
  `ItemsSource="{Binding People}"`, выделенная строка это свойство `SelectedEmployee`
  `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"`;
- текстбокс для Имя привязан к свойству `FirstName` у `ViewModel`
  `Text="{Binding FirstName}"`;
- к кнопке Сохранить привязано свойство `Save` в качестве команды
  `Command="{Binding Save}"`.

Вот класс для `ViewModel`

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Employee _selectedEmployee;
    private Employee _editableEmployee = new Employee(0);
    private List<Employee> _people;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainViewModel(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {

        EmployeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        Add = new AddEmployeeCommand(this);
        Save = new SaveEmployeeCommand(this);
        Delete = new DeleteEmployeeCommand(this);
        Next = new SelectNextCommand(this);
        Prev = new SelectPreviosCommand(this);

        LoadPeople().Await(HandleException);
    }

    //Загрузка из БД списка сотрудников
    public async Task LoadPeople()
    {
        var employees = await EmployeeRepository.GetEmployees();

        int id = 0;
        employees.ForEach(e => e.OrderNumber = ++id);
        People = employees;
    }

    //Обработка ошибки в случае LoadPeople()
    private void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        People = new List<Employee>();
    }

    //Ссылка на класс репозитория для работы с БД
    public IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository { get; }

    //--Команды для кнопок
    public ICommand Add { get; }
    public ICommand Save { get; }
    public ICommand Delete { get; }
    public ICommand Next { get; }
    public ICommand Prev { get; }

    //--Свойства
    //Отображаемая в DataGrid коллекция сотрудников
    public List<Employee> People
    {
        get => _people;
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(People)));
        }
    }

    //Выделенный в DataGrid сотрудник
    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get => _selectedEmployee;
        set
        {
            if (value == _selectedEmployee)
                return;
            _selectedEmployee = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedEmployee)));
            //Делаем копию для редактируемого сотрудника
            if (_selectedEmployee != null)
            {
                EditableEmployee = Employee.GetClone(_selectedEmployee);
            }
        }
    }

    //Редактируемый сотрудник
    public Employee EditableEmployee
    {
        get => _editableEmployee;
        set
        {
            _editableEmployee = value;
            //оповещаем View об изменении значений свойств
            //c помощью вызова события PropertyChanged для каждого привязанного свойства
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FirstName)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LastName)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Phone)));
        }
    }

    //Имя редактируемого
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _editableEmployee.FirstName;
        set => _editableEmployee.FirstName = value;
    }

    //Фамилия редактируемого
    public string LastName
    {
        get => _editableEmployee.LastName;
        set => _editableEmployee.LastName = value;
    }

    //Телефон редактируемого
    public string Phone
    {
        get => _editableEmployee.Phone;
        set => _editableEmployee.Phone = value;
    }
}
```

Пример реализации команды для кнопки `Сохранить` такой

```
class SaveEmployeeCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public SaveEmployeeCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        int result = 0;
        //если редактируемый новый
        if (_viewModel.EditableEmployee.Id == 0)
        {
            //то добавляем его
            result = await _viewModel.EmployeeRepository
                                     .AddEmployee(_viewModel.EditableEmployee);
        }
        else
        {
            //иначе обновляем
            result = await _viewModel.EmployeeRepository
                                     .UpdateEmployee(_viewModel.EditableEmployee);
        }

        if (result > 0)
        {
            _viewModel.EditableEmployee = new Employee(0);
            await _viewModel.LoadPeople();
        }
        else
        {
            //в случае неудачи...
        }
    }
}
```

Связка между собой `View`, `ViewModel` и репозитория в файле `App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //работа с данными в памяти
        var viewModel = new MainViewModel(new TestRepository());

        //или работа с данными из БД
        //var viewModel = new MainViewModel(new SqlRepository());

        //создаем въюшку
        var view = new MainView();
        //подключаем въюмодель в качестве источн.данных
        view.DataContext = viewModel;

        //окно программы
        var window = new MainWindow();
        //отображем въюшку
        window.Output.Content = view;
        //показываем окно
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Это конечно просто пример, а не законченное приложение.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, это пример много чего пояснил, но не стоило писать столько кода

Comment: Без много кода не получился бы полноценный пример 