# C#: как получить данные из таблицы бд

Tags: c#

помогите кто знает, с помощью какого объекта или метода я могу получить данные из таблицы базы данных, например как php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  $row["name"]
[image: рисунок c#]

Comment: https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/blob/master/WpfCRUD/WpfUI/Data/SqlRepository.cs  а весь пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1211324/222542)

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: Спасибо за очень подробное решение, но есть ли какие-нибудь решения для моему коду?

Comment: Начните с того, что перенесите свой код из конcтруктора формы как минимум в обработчик события `Form.Load`. Если это не сделать, однажды вы перестанете понимать, почему ваше приложение не запускается и не выдает никаких ошибок.

Comment: Код, который вы привели на скриншоте, делает как раз то, что вы просили: получает данные из таблицы БД.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинкой. Если кто-то захочет вставить ваш код в IDE и попробовать запустить - ему придётся перенабирать весь код заново, с риском опечататься. Уважайте желающих вам ответить -- вставляйте код текстом. Поставил минус вопросу за оформление.

Comment: Извиняюсь за оформлению след. раз буду внимательнее.

Comment: Исправьте вопрос, вы можете его редактировать. Вставьте код текстом. Если ответ ниже вам помог, можете отметить его принятым, галочка селва от ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Вот шаблон.

```
string connStr = "...";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT name FROM users";

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            names.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Попробуйте использовать EntityFramework, очень удобно, зная LINQ.

**Рекомендации**

Используйте `using` для кода, работающего с БД. Это обезопасит, не нужно каждый раз писать команды с `Close()` и `Dispose()`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает :)

Comment: то есть сработал

Answer (score -1):

private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DB db = new DB();
db.openConnection();

```
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM users";<br />
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, db.getConnection());<br />
    <h3>MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();<br />
    while (reader.Read())<br />
    {<br />
        listBox1.Items.Add((reader["Number"].ToString()));<br />
        listBox2.Items.Add((reader["Name"].ToString()));<br />
        listBox3.Items.Add((reader["Datetime"].ToString()));<br />
    }<br /></h3>
```

```
    db.closeConnection();<br />
}
```

Comment: Еще раз извиняюсь здесь редоктированием у меня проблемы.

Comment: Вам показали правильный код, а вы его обезобразили. НАДО использовать `using()`, а не писать как индусы на ютубе.

Comment: Мне надо было одну маленькую программу написать и показать работоспособность  к руководителю, поэтому не мчался на остальных проста  убрал table и добавил reader. Но вы правильно все пишите для дальнейших работ надо учитывать  все это.