# C# WPF MVVM Отображение данных в датагрид

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpf-datagrid

Имеется 2 окна. В одном (EmployeePage) окне DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="E_DataGrid" Grid.Row="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FIO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}" Width="*" Header="ФИО"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

И кнопка вызова другого (E_AddPage) окна:

```
<Button x:Name="E_Add" Click="E_Add_Click" Content="Добавить" />
```

В E_AddPage:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FIO_TextBox"  FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,30" Width="300" Height="25"  />
```

Используется паттерн MVVM, только начал его изучать, как и WPF в целом. Поэтому созданы еще 2 класса - Item.cs и ItemViewModel

Код Item.cs:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _fio;
          

    
    public string FIO
    {
        get
        {
            return this._fio;
            
        }

        set
        {
            _fio = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FIO");
        }
    }
        

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

Там много данных должно быть, но для удобства я сократил до одной (FIO)

Код ItemViewModel:

```
class ItemViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item{FIO="131" /*ProductName="435", OrderNumber=421124, PurchaseDate="432432453", DeliveryAvailability=true, DeliveryDate="244"*/ }
        };
    }


    public void AddItem()
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        Items.Insert(0, item);
        
    }


}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы с текстбокса одного окна занисились данные в датагрид другого окна?

Comment: Подсказка: `OnPropertyChanged("FIO")` можно заменить на просто `OnPropertyChanged()`, так как `[CallerMemberName]` сам подставит нужное значение.

Comment: Тут 2 варианта возможны: 1) Открыто главное окно с таблицей, нажимаем кнопку, открывается поверх другое окно, вводим там данные, нажимаем ОК, окно закрывается, в таблицу добавляются новые данные; 2) Отрыты сразу 2 окна, в одно окно вводим, в другом данные добавляются в таблицу. Вам какой вариант нужен? С другой стороны общая тенденция в создании UI такая, что вся работа происходит только в одном окне, как в браузере или в мобильном приложении; переходы между страницами, и никакие доп.окна не открываются. Посмотрите [примерчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1211324/222542) может пригодится.

Comment: @Bulson Мне нужен 1 вариант. Сейчас посмотрю ваш пример

Comment: Есть [еще примерчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135478/373567), попроще, опять же без окон.

Comment: У вас вопрос `Как мне сделать так, чтобы с текстбокса одного окна занисились данные в датагрид другого окна?`, но вы не показывается как окно открывается, как вы сами пытаетесь туда передать данные, вы просто показали разметку кнопки (где нарушаете MVVM, ибо используете событие `Click`) и показываете ваши данные, все. От нас тогда вы что хотите, чтоб мы за вас написали открытие нового окна? Ок, тогда это дубликат.