# Занесение строк в базу данных MySQL из приложения WF

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Создал приложение на WinForms для работы с базой данных, но при занесении строк на русском языке вместо русских символов в БД получаю "????". Я думаю, что это связано с кодировкой. На сервере с БД стоит кодировка utf8_general_ci. Возможно, в VS стоит другая кодировка. Я пробовал менять кодировку у строки, но получал либо такой же результат, либо другой, но не лучше. С английскими символами всё хорошо. Раньше такой проблемы не было, но она появилась сама по себе.

```
MySqlCommand genreAdditionCommand = new MySqlCommand($"INSERT INTO `genre` (`id`, `DENOMINATION`) VALUES (NULL, @denom);", db.getConnection());
        genreAdditionCommand.Parameters.Add("@denom", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = genreName.Text;
        db.openConnection();
```

genreName - элемент графического интерфейса TextBox

Comment: Посмотрите [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1043980/222542), в самом конце ответа есть код класса `MySqlRepository` и в методе `GetConnection()` есть настройка `builder.CharacterSet = "utf8";`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Правда, в моём случае мне просто нужно было указать после всех данных БД при подключении characterset=utf8, чтобы строка выглядела так: DB.Connection = $"server={getHost.Text};port={getPort.Text};username={getLogin.Text};password={getPass.Text};database=admin_gallery;characterset=utf8";